# build ml model for text classification usin logistic regression, bow,countvectorizer.getting value error for new input point

Tags: python, machine-learning

trying to classify new text input point into positive negative neutral using pre build model and getting value error.i have a new review which needs to be vectorized using count vectorizer but even after vectorizing the shape doesnt change. it  works fine on train and test data set

```
used logistic regression
bag of words
count vectorization

# Create an object of class CountVectorizer
bow = CountVectorizer()
## X_train.values.shape
# Call the fit_transform method on training data
X_train = bow.fit_transform(X_train_raw.values)
# Call the transform method on the test dataset
X_test = bow.transform(X_test_raw.values)
#perform column standardaiztion
std = StandardScaler(with_mean=False)
X_train = std.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = std.transform(X_test)
start = time.time()
# creating list of C
C_values = np.linspace(0.1,1,10)

cv_scores = [] # empty list that will hold cv scores

# Try each value of alpha in the below loop
for c in C_values:
    # Create an object of the class Logistic Regression with balanced class weights
    clf = LogisticRegression(C = c, class_weight = 'balanced')
    # perform 5-fold cross validation
    # It returns the cv accuracy for each fold in a list
    scores = cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
    # Store the mean of the accuracies from all the 5 folds
    cv_scores.append(scores.mean())

# calculate misclassification error from accuracy (error = 1 - accuracy)
cv_error = [1 - x for x in cv_scores]

# optimal (best) C is the one for which error is minimum (or accuracy is maximum)
optimal_C = C_values[cv_error.index(min(cv_error))]
print('\nThe optimal alpha is', optimal_C)

end = time.time()
print("Total time in minutes = ", (end-start)/60)
clf = LogisticRegression(C = optimal_C)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
acc = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred) * 100
print("Accuracy =", acc)
confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

def predict_new(X):
  #  X1 = [[X]]
    X2 = [X]
    X4= pd.Series(X2)
    X3,los = data_cleaning(X4)
    #print(X3.values)
    X_t = bow.transform(X3)
    print(X_t.shape)
    #X_t= std.transform(X_t)
    #pred = clf.predict(X_t)
    pred =0
    if pred ==  1:
        print("Positive")
    elif pred == -1:
        print("Negative")
    else:
        print("Neutral")
predict_new('the app is good')
```

I expected the output to be positive negative or neutral